# Utilisation de « mec/meuf »

Tags: usage, société, registre

J'ai demandé à mon professeur de français, elle m'a dit « Oublie ces mots », parce que ces mots sont mauvais. Mais j'entends souvent ces mots dans les films. Puis-je les utiliser ? Et dans quelles situations ? Ces mots peuvent-ils être une insulte ?

Comment: J'habite au Canada et je crois que ces mots ne sont utilisés qu'en France. Je ne pense pas qu'ils peuvent être une insulte, ce sont par contre des mots utilisés seulement dans des situations informelles.

Comment: À comparer avec « gars » et « nana » aussi.

Comment: Les reponses donnees sont satisfaisantes mais a mes yeux, _meuf_ peut avoir une nuance pejorative, donc a utiliser avec doigte.

Comment: Il faut insister sur la différence de langage entre "mec" et "meuf". "Mec" est à la limite entre le familier et le courant, alors que meuf est à la limite entre le familier et le vulgaire...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Mec* est un mot qui est dans la langue française depuis le 19<sup>e</sup> siècle avec le sens de « souteneur ». De nos jours il est aussi utilisé pour désigner de façon populaire, mais pas vulgaire, un individu de sexe masculin.
On le trouve dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mec).

*Meuf* est un mot entré récemment dans la langue française, c'est le [verlan](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/verlan) de *femme*. Il n'est pas dans le TLF mais il est couramment employé dans la langue orale peu soutenue, et plutôt par des jeunes.
 Pour le contexte d'emploi je suis d'accord avec ce que dit Nikko.

> Mate un peu cette meuf !

Là le contexte est clair (bande copains qui discutent entre eux), renforcé par « mate » qui situe le contexte de discours oral argotique. L'emploi est vulgaire.

Et la remarque serait tout aussi vulgaire s'ils disaient :

> Mate un peu cette fille !

Sauf que le mot *fille* sonnerait un peu déplacé dans le contexte.

Si mon mec me dit :

> T'es ma meuf.

Ça n'a rien de vulgaire, c'est affectueux.

---

Je trouve regrettable qu'un enseignant demande à un apprenant d'oublier des mots avec la raison qu'ils sont « mauvais ». L'emploi des mots dépend du contexte et à un certain niveau d’apprentissage il est important de pouvoir comprendre tout une étendue de registres et de pouvoir employer les mots justes dans une situation donnée.

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres Et dans beaucoup d'autres dictionnaires. Le TLF est ici une référence.

Comment: Accepter "T'es ma meuf." de maniere affectueuse, c'est un sentiment partage par la majorite de la gente feminine ?

Comment: @oldergod non pas du tout, pour moi c'est le genre de phrase que pourrait sortir une racaille affectueusement, mais autrement ça aurait une connotation plutôt dégradante.

Comment: @oldergod Là encore c'est une question de contexte, quelqu'un qui parle de son mec prendra l'appellation ma meuf de façon affectueuse. Le contexte est aussi une question de génération et de lieu. Par contre rien à voir avec le fait d'être une racaille ou non.

Comment: Ce sont des mots d'argot (mec, ancien, comme flic, et beaucoup), et meuf (plus récent, comme keuf, et toute une série découlant du verlan), donc à réserver au langage familier ou très familier. Ce n'est pas la notion de vulgaire, qui s'attache plutôt à une expression ou une construction.

Comment: +1 pour la dernière paragraphe. A mon avis c'est idiot «d'oublier» des mots - car, si on sait le contexte/registre de leur emploi, ça ne fait qu'aider à comprendre la langue. Bien sûr il faut faire attention aux gros mots et l'usage du vocabulaire dans un registre ou un autre; je n'utiliserais jamais *meuf* avec des profs, cependant je l'avais souvent entendu quand j'étudias en France, et il fallait comprendre le mot pour comprendre la conversation dans laquelle je faisais partie. *Oublier des mots*, c'est un truc de fou.

Comment: Oublier des mots veut sans doute dire "ne pas les utiliser". Ce n'est pas comme si on pouvait forcer qui que ce soit à oublier quoi que ce soit. La dramatisation ne sert pas le propos.

Answer (score 10):

C'est très informel, mais c'est aussi très utilisé dans la vie de tous les jours (entre amis par ex..).

*Mec* est plus vieux (l'expression date du XIXe siècle) et plutôt très utilisé, on pourrait même l'utiliser avec des collègues de travail (*tu as vu le mec de chez Entreprise XY ?*).

*Meuf* est une expression récente et plutôt vulgaire dans beaucoup de situations mais peut-être utilisé entre jeunes amis : *amène ta meuf* sans que ça pose de problème. Pas au bureau par contre. Hors contexte amical il faut faire attention à son utilisation, cela pourrait être très mal pris.

Answer (score 7):

*Meuf* et *mec* ne sont pas des mots que je conseillerais à un étranger. Dans le cadre professionnel ces mots peuvent être très mal pris, de même avec toute personne n'étant pas habituée à ce langage peu soutenu, surtout pour le mot *meuf* qui est plutôt vulgaire voire carrément dévalorisant pour une femme.

Comment: Oui mais une personne en France tombera tot ou tard dessus. Surtout "mec", très utilisé. Je ne vois pas pourquoi on "oublierait" des mots que tout le monde utilise à l'oral.

Comment: Je conseille simplement de ne pas les employer pour quelqu'un qui risque de mal les maitriser. Mais les est tout a fait possible des utiliser lorsqu'on en connait la portée. De plus même si Dmytry ne les emploie pas, il peut les comprendre. Il n'est pas question ici d'oublier quoi que ce soit.

Answer (score 3):

As a french teenager (boy), we often use "mec" to call each other.
"Meuf" is kind of the equivalent word for this with girls.

We only use this between friends or other teenagers.

Answer (score 2):

Étant Française je peux affirmer que le terme meuf appartient au langage courant. On l'utilise souvent dans le langage parlé : c'est un terme affectif qu'on utilise par exemple pour appeler sa copine.

Exemple :

> meuf, je t'ai pas dit...

Le mot n'est pas vulgaire; il n'appartient simplement pas au langage soutenu ce qui explique peut-être pourquoi ton professeur te l'a déconseillé mais cela était totalement injustifié car si un jour tu viens en France ou si tu as des amies là-bas c'est un terme fréquemment utilisé.

Meuf peut aussi qualifier une petite amie tout comme une jeune fille lambda, c'est un terme avec plusieurs sens.

Answer (score 0):

Je suis une femme du Québec et personnellement, je détesterais me faire appeler ou qualifier de meuf. Pour moi ça sonne comme le mot bœuf qui au féminin est une vache. Je trouve très laid ce mot

Comment: Je vis en France, et je n'aime pas non plus, mais ceci est plutôt un commentaire, pas une réponse. Il faudrait plus de sources ou d'analyse pour en faire une réponse.

Comment: Bonjour et bienvenue sur French Language, @Nathalie ! En l'état cette réponse est uniquement subjective, ne répond pas vraiment à la question et n'apporte pas beaucoup de contexte à son affirmation. Pour l'améliorer, tu peux en dire plus sur la façon dont ce mot est perçu plus généralement au Québec et éventuellement donner des sources et essayer de répondre davantage à la question posée.

Answer (score 0):

C'est clairement du langage familier. A utiliser avec des amis proche/camarades de classe, surtout si on est jeune.

Au passage : **Mec** est bien plus ancien (19e siècle voir [cnrtl](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/mec))  que **Meuf** qui signifie juste **femme** en verlan, mais n'était pas utilisé pour apostropher comme on l'entend maintenant (`Hé, meuf`, par ex.)

**Meuf** semble donc aujourd'hui utilisé quasiment comme le féminin de **mec**.