# Que signifie « faire sa meuf » ?

Tags: expressions, langage-des-jeunes

Que signifie *faire sa meuf* ? J'ai entendu dire un mec à un autre : « fais pas ta meuf ». J'ai recherché un peu sur l'internet et j'ai l'impression que cette expression s'emploie surtout pour des femmes, non ?

Comment: Une meuf c'est une femme. http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17315/utilisation-de-mec-meuf

Comment: C'est le verlan (http://french.about.com/od/vocabulary/a/verlan.htm)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> "Fais pas ton/ta X"

Signifie (de manière familière):

> "Arrête de te comporter comme un/une X"

Une "meuf" c'est une "femme" en verlan.

Avec "fais pas ta meuf", on dit à l'autre d'arrêter de se comporter comme une femme. C'est une expression sexiste : on entend par là "arrête de te plaindre", "arrête de pleurer", "arrête de passer deux heures devant chaque vitrine"...

Answer (score 10):

On peut aussi dire « fais pas ton petit joueur », « fais pas ta chochotte ».

On dit ça à un homme qui a peur de faire par exemple quelque chose de sensation.

Comme le dit @Laure, une meuf c'est une femme. L'expression est basée sur le cliché qu'une femme est moins forte qu'un homme. un cliché je dis bien :-)

Answer (score 1):

En plus des réponses précédentes, je l'ai aussi souvent entendu dans un contexte bien différent.
Dit à une femme ou alors "fait pas ton mec" pour un homme, "fait pas ta meuf" permet de remettre qu'un à ça place. Faire remarquer à qq'un qu'il se plastronne (aka. se la raconte).